# Adding page number to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I need to have a roman page number on the first page of the TOC, but the page number on that page is skipped. Is there a way to add a page number to the first page of the TOC? Here is a short version of the code, with my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
\newpage

\begin{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \copyright{}
\end{center}
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{tree.png}}
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\clearpage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Dedication}
\setcounter{page}{4}
...
\newpage

\chapter{Acknowledgements}
...
\newpage

\chapter{Preface}
...
\newpage
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
...
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{10}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\newpage

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part*{Introduction}
\label{part-1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Introduction}
...
\setcounter{page}{1}
...

{
\backmatter
\singlespacing
\setglossarysection{part}
\printglossaries
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Bibliography}
}
\end{document}
```

Any pointers would be of great help!
Thanks,
f

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!Please post a short, but complete code,, including your documentclass, &c.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, thanks. I edited my code above with the document class. Is there anything else you would need? I omitted packages since I did not think they were relevant.

Comment: Ok, now it is compilable. To my surprise, the page number appears correctly in the example. But, on my large project (+200 pages, 7 chapters, etc) it simply doesn't.

Comment: Would it help if I post a link to the complete code?

Comment: I understand. I have a compilation routine with 5 steps: pdflatex, makeglossaries, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex.

Comment: Ok. I moved hyperref to the end with glossaries after it. Then, I compiled with pdflatex two times. After the first pdflatex, I get an empty "Contents" page with correct page number. After the second pdflatex, I get the full TOC without page number on the first page. I don't understand why!

Comment: Well, thank you for your suggestion but it did not succeed. I tried it with my 5-step compile routine and the page number still does not display. Is there a way to set `\tableofcontents` options? I could not find any documentation on how to do so.

Comment: Thank you, @KJO, I managed to make it work. Check out my answer below. You were right that "page numbers are "changing" a lot"! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after fiddling with the suggestions in the comments, I realized the code was a bit messy, with too many `\thispagestyle{empty}`, `\thispagestyle{plain}`, and `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}`.

My solution was to simply use one `\pagestyle{empty}` for all pages in the `\frontmatter` that did not require page numbers, and then one `\pagestyle{plain}` for the sections that did require them. Since the `\tableofcontents` appeared within this last group, the solution was as simple as that. However, I also removed unecessary `\addtocontents` calls. The `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` was also needed only once.

I paste here a revised version of the code above:

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}    % <-- added this
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
\newpage

\begin{center}
    %  \thispagestyle{empty} <-- removed
    %  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} <-- removed
    % \pagenumbering{gobble} <-- removed
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \copyright{}
\end{center}
\newpage

%  \thispagestyle{empty} <-- removed
%  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} <-- removed
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{tree.png}}
%  \newpage  <-- removed

%  \thispagestyle{empty} <-- removed
%  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} <-- removed
\clearpage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}    %  <-- added this

\chapter{Dedication}
\setcounter{page}{4} % (this shouldn't be necessary, but I kept it)

...
\newpage

\chapter{Acknowledgements}
...
\newpage

\chapter{Preface}
...
\newpage
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
...
%  \newpage  <-- removed
%  \pagenumbering{roman}    <-- removed
%  \setcounter{page}{10}    <-- removed
%  \thispagestyle{plain}    <-- removed
\tableofcontents
%  \thispagestyle{plain}    <-- removed
```

The rest is the same as above. Thanks for your help, while not directly solving the issue, @KJO helped me figure out the problem! Best,

f